# Terraform GKE - Secondary range does not exist in network

Tags: terraform

I get the error `Secondary range  "private-subnet-a" does not exist in network`  but it exists and have a compute engine VM's running as a result I can't delete and recreate it.

The issue started after I made some changes to the cluster and tried to rebuild the GKE cluster using terraform.

[image]

```
Error: Error waiting for creating GKE cluster: Retry budget exhausted (80 attempts): Secondary range "private-subnet-a" does not exist in network "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-a-39823/global/networks/testing" , subnetwork "private-subnet-a".
```

Here is the terraform code:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  depends_on = [var.depends_on_vpc]
  name     = "testing"
  network  = "testing"
  subnetwork = "private-subnet-a"
  location               = "us-west1-a"
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count = 1


  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name = "private-subnet-a"
    services_secondary_range_name = "private-subnet-a"
  }

  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_nodes = "true"
    enable_private_endpoint = "false" # this option will make your cluster available through public endpoint
    master_ipv4_cidr_block = "10.x.x.0/28"
  }

  maintenance_policy {

    daily_maintenance_window {
      start_time = "02:00"
    }
  }

}
```